# Firebase Database multiple strings in one child

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, kotlin, hashmap

im working with firebase for a couple months and so far i had no issues until now. im using kotlin and my problem is simple but i cant find a way out. i storage strings in database: path"/user/friends" , but i cant change the variable name and the strings were overwriting itselves. My solution was use "push()" until the "setValue()", but with this i have the following firebase structure:

```
"users": {
    "yvrYpjMwVSPBvMAvDGo26hPlWWQ2": {
        "email": "vinibarros.sp@gmail.com",
        "friends": {
            "-LfD9z6ke7FXFjxUb4td": {
                "email": "teste@gmail.com"
            },
            "-LfDA-NaAYAMoWiPhXy4": {
                "email": "teste2@gmail.com"
            }
        },
        "primeiroLogin": true,
        "stars": 0,
        "tutorialComplete": false,
        "uid": "yvrYpjMwVSPBvMAvDGo26hPlWWQ2",
        "username": "Vinicius Barros"
    }
}
```

basically hashmaps inside a hashmap ps:lol mindblow

how do i get the pushcode.value into an arraylist?

i have a class user that have the friend variable, until now this variable was typed as hashMap. and the call to get the email was "user.friends.value"

this worked because was one friend....

> com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseException: Failed to convert value of type java.util.HashMap to String

When I added more than one user I got this error that references my class user, where have a "hashMap". But the firebase gives me another hashmap instead of string. I was thinking about: `hashMap<hashMap<String,String>, null>`.

i 've tried this:

class friends:

```
@Parcelize
class Friend(val hashMap: HashMap < String, String > ? ): Parcelable {
    constructor(): this(null)
}
```

The activity where i show the friends:

```
val ref2 = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("/users/" + cUid + "/friends/")
ref2.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(object: ValueEventListener {
    override fun onCancelled(p0: DatabaseError) {

    }
    override fun onDataChange(p0: DataSnapshot) {
        p0.children.forEach {
            val friend = it.getValue(Friend::class.java)
            Log.d("teste", it.toString())
            if (friend != null) {
                Log.d("teste", friend.hashMap ? .values.toString())
                //friends.add(friend.hashMap?.values.toString())
            }
        }

    }

})
```

this keeps returning null....

Comment: Also: replace the JSON-like structure, with the actual JSON you're trying to read (as text, no screenshot). You can get this by clicking the "Export JSON" link in the overflow menu (⠇) on your [Firebase Database console](https://console.firebase.google.com/project/_/database/data).

Comment: see if it is better now, sorry

Answer (score 1):

With your `Friend` class, the Firebase client looks for a JSON for each friend with this structure:

```
"-LfD9z6ke7FXFjxUb4td": {
    "hashMap": {
        ...
    }
},
```

This is because you're defining your `Friend` class with a property `hashMap` like this: `class Friend(val hashMap: HashMap < String, String > ? )`.

To be able to read your current structure, you'll need to define a `data class` like this:

```
data class Friend (
    val email: String? = null
}
```

Now the `email` in the `Friend` class matched the `email` property in the JSON. And since `email` has a default value, the `Friend` class will have a default no-argument constructor, which Firebase relies on.

Answer (score 0):

Solved!

After get into /friends
i did this:

```
 var friends : ArrayList<String> = arrayListOf()
```

the onDataChanged where i get the string friend

```
     override fun onDataChange(p1: DataSnapshot) {
                                          p1.children.forEach { it1 ->
                                              val friend = it1.value as String

                                                  friends.add(friend)


                                          }
                                      }
```